# Connection speed problem

Tags: networking, internet, hardware

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have not a lot of experience with hardware in linux. I built a working machine with a ASUS Prime Z390-A motherboard and a ASUS AX3000 (PCE-AX58BT) wifi controller.

My internet speed is not constant, and I have a lot of drop in the connection. After reading a couple of article online I end up thinking the problem was the support for this "new" technology, so I decided to connect through RJ45. Since my router is not accessible easily for cable I bought a TRENDnet TPL-407E2K to pass the ethernet through electrical outlet.

My speed haven't changed!

If I do a speedtest with my main computer (under windows) I have P:10ms D:520Mbps UP:505Mbps, but If I try with the Ubuntu machine I reach barely 80Mbps Up and Down, with a 30ms ping and I have connection dropping!

Since i'm now through RJ45 I can't blame the WIFI, and since the WIFI and the Ethernet controller are not on the same card, all I can blame is Ubuntu setup ?

Please help me figure this out, I'm out of luck right now!

---

- Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
- Description:  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Release:  20.04
- Codename: focal
- Linux 5.8.0-36-generic x86_64
- Linux version 5.8.0-36-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-027) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021

Comment: @guiverc I've added information that I knew how to extract. If you need more specific, maybe you can just tell me what to type. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a combination of one issue with the wireless and another with the gigabit connection. First let's look at the wired connection:

Your motherboard has an Intel I219V Gigabit ethernet port, and the I219V can sometimes have some speed negotiation issues with the host switch. What I've had to do in these cases is outlined below.

*On the switch/router:*

1. Set the connection negotiation to manual
2. Set the speed to 1Gbps

*Note that this can cause problems if you have slower devices also connected to the switch/router.*

If you cannot change the settings on the switch/router for whatever reason, you *may* be able to set the speed locally on a per-connection basis. What this means is that if you unplug the network then plug it in again, these settings will be reset:

1. Install `ethtool`: `apt install ethtool`
2. Set the speed to full-speed duplex without negotiation:
   `ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off`

***Important:** Be sure to change* `eth0` *to whatever your device name happens to be.*

As for the wireless, this is *usually* a problem related to the power saving mode of the device. You can typically get full speed from your wireless by doing this:

1. Open the `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` file. You will see something that looks like this:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3
```

2. Change `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2`
3. Reboot

Hope this helps you get the most from your network connections.

Comment: Will definitely try that by the end of this morning thank you.

Comment: Ok, so I just tried it, and when I type the ethtool command my wired connection disapear, I have to reboot to get it back then it still 100Mb/s link. 

I also changed the wifi settings and reboot and still with the same speed. Can't say if I will still get drop on load, but will update later today if I have problem with it.