# Swap installation between two computers

Tags: hardware

> **This is another question, in link with ( [Connection speed problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307848/connection-speed-problem)) for a possible solution**

Since I have problem with "newer" hardware, is it possible to swap my hard drive (NVME) to another computer with older parts (5yr) then just boot this computer with the swapped nvme ? Will that work ? Do I have to prepare something ? I know that Windows will not handle that since driver will be confused, but is Ubuntu smarter ?

Thank you!

Comment: I haven't done it with NVME drive, but I've swapped drives between machines and had it work flawlessly (different age & model machines), but also had it fail to work (or given problems inc. same brand & model hardware). Make sure all packages required for the new/other hardware are pre-installed before the move is all I can suggest.

Comment: Okay cool! It can be a good idea to try it out tonight then ! Maybe I'll fix my problems !